# How to implement multiple login session simultaneously in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session

I have 2 sites that I'm working on;

1. admin site
2. user(consumer) site

Requirement wise, admin can click the users data on the admin's page, this will open a new tab(in the same browser) and the admin is logged in into the users account (internally logged in as the user itself, having an "admin-flag" turned on on the user session to differentiate if normal user or admin) to do certain actions.

For example, admin can click user1,user2,user3 and this will open 3 new tabs in the browser (user1 in tab number 1, user2 in tab number 2 and so on).
The admin can then perform actions on the user account on each tab.

Now, this is where I am having a hard time.

> Admin can login into multiple user account, **simultaneously**

I have zero experience in managing multiple sessions of authenticated users simultaneously.

I know that it is possible by using some GET parameter (for example, https://user-site/top/?session-key=1) where `session-key` is to indicate which session the user is and in the backend use it to get the appropriate auth session amongst the other auth sessions.
But as far I as know, Laravel doesn't support this out of the box.

My question is,

**Is there a recommended way of implementing this in Laravel?**

I could go all over the code where Session is used an tweak it so that it uses the `session-key` to access the sessions and create my own guard,

For example, in SessionGuard, I could store auth sessions in an array, and afterward pick the appropriate session by its key from the `session-key` (which mean I have to append all request with `session-key` GET parameter!):

↓↓ Updating auth sessions ↓↓

```
/**
 * Update the session with the given ID.
 *
 * @param  string  $id
 * @return void
 */
protected function updateSession($id)
{
  $authSessions = $this->session->get('auth-sessions'); // retrieve all auth sessions
  $sessionKey = request()->get('session-key'); // retrieve session-key from GET parameter
  $authSessions[$sessionKey] = $id; // store session separately by session-key

  $this->session->put('auth-sessions', $authSessions); // store all auth sessions

  $this->session->migrate(true);
}
```

↓↓ Consuming auth sessions ↓↓

```
$authSessions = session()->get('auth-sessions'); // retrieve all auth sessions
$sessionKey = request()->get('session-key'); // retrieve session-key from GET parameter

return $authSessions[$sessionKey]; // return the appropriate session
```

Or even create a custom Session object (which is scary considering Session is widely used internally in Laravel...).

Have anyone had the same experience? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a repository specifically for this kind of system: https://github.com/aceraven777/laravel-5-4-boilerplate

What I did here is in the `config/auth.php` I created 2 guards, `web` is for the regular consumers and `admin` for admin users.

You can read the `readme.md` there in my repository for the complete details.

Comment: I checked it out, but does it enable multiple sessions simultaneously?
For example, I can login more than 1 account to web (regular customer) at the same time, and further login more accounts while not overwriting other login session.